# What these MySQL global variables really mean?

Tags: mysql

Today I contacted a hosting company to get information about their Java hosting performance. In their response, they said

```
MySQL:
max_connections=300
max_user_connections=50

Apache:
MaxClients 150 (this mean that 150 query could be handling at once, all other queries will be put to the queue).
```

Now I am confused. I read the NySQL developer document seeking for an answer but I am not convinced enough. Here are my questions;

1. What is the difference between `max_connections` and `max_user_connections` ?
2. Does it mean only 300 people can use the site at once? Or only 50 people? or something else?

The application I have is an online HR package, where users and their sub users will log into and perform operations like insert, delete, update. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**1. What is the difference between max_connections and max_user_connections ?**

The variable `max_connections` defines the max permitted number of simultaneous client connections. The variable `max_user_connections` instead defines the max number of simultaneous connections permitted to any given MySQL user account.

**2. Does it mean only 300 people can use the site at once? Or only 50 people? or something else?**

As i said before the `max_connections` are set to 300, so for the MySQL database you are able to use 300 different clients. The apache server allows only 150 clients which means you server not able to talk to more clients than 150. But I think the most significant problem is that you application probably use only one MySQL user to operate on the MySQL Tables which means you are
bound to the `max_user_connections`. If you use more than one MySQL user you are only bound from the apache config which means 150 clients only.

See the documentation of the System variables:

[max_connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections)

[max_user_connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections)

Comment: If you are talking about the mysql users where we can create from "phpMyAdmin", we only have one user, that is "hrUser". Now, can you only 50 people can access this system at once???? :O

Comment: Yes, but you can change the server variable to 0 so there is no limit for the connections.

Comment: It cannot be changed from the host.

Comment: Any idea about max_user_connection at amazon RDS?

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/599421/highest-value-of-max-connections-in-aws-rds-micro-instance    But in you position i would add more mysql users and use them alternating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78994/discussion-between-zelldon-and-justcause).